# How to get address or symbol of the usage of a constant located in rodata?

Tags: objdump, address, section

I have an elf executable. I found a string (awesome string) in my `.rodata` section:

```
$ mb-readelf -p 10 a.out

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     0]  Hello world
...
  [  ab12]  awesome string
...
```

Here are the sections:

```
$ readelf -S a.out
There are 27 section headers, starting at offset 0x10150:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
...
  [10] .rodata           PROGBITS        00004fc8 00a030 001394 00   A  0   0  4
...
```

So the address of awesome string is `00004fc8 + ab12 = 14ada`

I want to know which functions are using this awesome string. How can I know who references the address 14ada?

Comment: using what ? your code? / a decent disassembler /  how are you looking most decent disassembler will cross reference the string

Answer (score 1):

## It cannot be solved in all cases.

Some string (start) is not referenced in the whole `text` at all, even if you turned on all optimizations. Let's see the following example.

```
#define _FILE strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__
```

`_FILE` will point the filename instead of the full path, however, the compiled `elf` will contain the whole `__FILE__` string (the whole path) (See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31050113/2506522).)

In this case, `.rodata` will be seen like this:

```
$ readelf -p 10 a.out

String dump of section '.rodata':
  [     0]  Hello world
...
  [  ab12]  /your/build/folder/awesome.c
...
```

While the `text` will *not* refer the `0xab12` anywhere, because `_FILE`  points to `0xab25` (the start of the `awesome.c`) and the `text` will refer to this `0xab25` adress.

A workaround can be that checking all offsets of a given string.

---

## Solution

The following solution works with MicroBlaze GCC, but the solution approach is general, so it can be applied to all architecture.

Find a known string in `rodata`. (A string with known usage. For example print a Hello world message at the beginning of the main.) Check out the compiled assembly. MicroBlaze GCC uses the strings in `printf` as following:

```
00000100 <main>:
...
     1ec:       b0000000        imm     0
     1f0:       30a09fc8        addik   r5, r0, -24632  // This is the HELLO WORLD
     1f4:       31000004        addik   r8, r0, 4
     1f8:       11330000        addk    r9, r19, r0
     1fc:       b9f45a58        brlid   r15, 23128      // 6954 <printf>
```

So this compiler refers the addresses as 16 bit signed values.

To get the referring code line, convert the `0xfada` (the absolute address of the `awesome string`) to 16 bit signed integer `-1318` and search (grep) for this value in the disassembled `text`.

Answer (score 0):

As i commented a decent disassembler will already do this for you

here  is sample output for a random awesome string  in a random binary using radare2

```
radare2 on cdb.exe from windbg in win7 x86 

grepping  for some awesome string 
[0x00416870]> iz~deb
006 0x00018280 0x00419080  12  26 (.data) utf16le debugger.chm  <<<< an awesome string 

printing crossrefs

[0x00416870]> axg @0x419080
- 0x00419080
  - 0x00413cfe fcn 0x00413c6c fcn.00413c6c
  - 0x00413c6c fcn 0x00413c6c fcn.00413c6c
    - 0x00416755 ???
  - 0x00413d17 fcn 0x00413c6c fcn.00413c6c
  - 0x00413d2b fcn 0x00413c6c fcn.00413c6c
  - 0x00413d38 fcn 0x00413c6c fcn.00413c6c
 
 looking at the listed cross refs
[0x00416870]> pd1@0x413cfe
|           0x00413cfe      6880904100     push str.debugger.chm       ; 0x419080 ; u"debugger.chm"
[0x00416870]> pd1@0x413d17
|           0x00413d17      6880904100     push str.debugger.chm       ; 0x419080 ; u"debugger.chm"
[0x00416870]> pd1@0x413d2b
|           0x00413d2b      66a380904100   mov word str.debugger.chm, ax ; [0x419080:2]=100 ; u"debugger.chm"
[0x00416870]> pd1@0x413d38
|           0x00413d38      b980904100     mov ecx, str.debugger.chm   ; 0x419080 ; u"debugger.chm"
[0x00416870]>
```